# How can we do a "zoom in" feature when clicked on a tab of a website with html?

Tags: html, zooming

I have a page which is designed in HTML, and there are some tabs on the left side of the page. Now if I click one a tab, it has to display the page with a Zoom-in feature (i.e. that tab has to come with zoom-in and the remaining page will be at the background of the particular zoom-out tab).

For clear understanding, see [this site](http://facepark.org/) which is done through Flash. The same thing I want, but with the use of HTML controls.

Could anybody face this problem? Please suggest on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: That site you refer to does not _zoom_ by clicking the tabs. It pans the page. Any change you mean panning (or moving, centering) the page rather then zooming? If so, please edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do this thing with jquery.

on mouseover a particular element change its css to increase size and to change z-index.

you can get help on this thing from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp)